# php check if string contains some letters/numbers

Tags: php, string, numbers, contains, letters

I have some string in which I would like to check if contains some letters or numbers. Those letters are from a-z, A-Z and all numbers.

So this is the example:
$goodstring = "abcdefg%$#%&asdqwe";
$badstring = "%$#&%#/&/#$%!#-.";

check if $goodstring contains letters/numbers and if, then return true.
check if $badstring contains letters/numbers and if not, then return false.

I have also used preg_match, but this works only if there are not some letters/numbers in string.

Comment: you want to check if the string contains only letters a-z, A-Z and numbers or you want to check if it contains at least one of those?

Comment: **I have also used preg_match**. You might've done it wrong. Why not share what you tried?

Comment: I want check if contains any letter/number - it's not important if there is one or more, just shouldn't contains characters %$#!&

I tried this, but don't work good: preg_match("/^([a-zA-Z0-9])+$/i", $badstring)

Comment: @user1257255 so you want to check if it contains ONLY alphanumerics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go ("*only*" version):

```
$containsOnlyLettersOrNumbers = (preg_match('~^[0-9a-z]+$~i', $string) > 0);
```

Or (depending on what you want exactly):

```
$containsLettersOrNumbers = (preg_match('~[0-9a-z]~i', $string) > 0);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var_dump(preg_match('#[0-9]|[a-z]#i', $goodstring));
var_dump(preg_match('#[0-9]|[a-z]#i', $badstring));
```